# Can't read a jpeg with skimage

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to run this code but it does not work. google- I look, but I have not found the answer, but I look in vain here

```
from skimage import io
photo = io.imread('C:\Users\comp\Desktop\Urban.jpg')
type(photo)
```

The answer should be as follows:
numpy.ndarray

Error:

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: what is your actual behavior? an error? nothing happens?

Comment: Why did you tag this unicode? I don't see any apparent unicode peculiarities.

Comment: Is wrong.
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Please [edit] the full error (traceback) into your question.

Comment: Have you actually tried searching for the error message?

Comment: Use forward slashes in your path: that's more uniform, and avoids issues such as `\U` being interpretated differently.

Comment: use double slash instead of single slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of single slash use double slash

```
from skimage import io
photo = io.imread('C:\\Users\\comp\\Desktop\\Urban.jpg')
type(photo)
```

Comment: I can confirm it in 4 minutes.

Comment: welcome,please confirm it as answer